# Mail merge (Excel to word) How to limt the decimals on the word document?

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have entered a formula which unfortunately results in a multiple decimal answer. My problem now is, I would like to do a mail-merge from Excel into word but unfortuntely the word document keeps on reflecting all the decimals despite all efforts to limit the decimals in excel. Please help

Comment: What is your formula in the word document? (field properties)

Answer (score 1):

Within the braces of you merge field, enter:

```
\# ",0.00"
```

i.e.,

```
{ MERGEFIELD BalanceDue \# ",0.00" }
```

The leading backslash (`\`) and pound sign (`#`) says to format as a number,
the number format within the double quotes says to put a comma between the thousands and hundreds digits, and display two decimal points.  You can put a `$` before the comma if you are formatting it for financial reports.

`1234567.90123` will be displayed in the merged word doc as 
`1,234,567.90`

There is no rounding.

If there are no decimal values, it will display `.00` at the end

Answer (score 0):

You need to format the output as text in excel:

=TEXT(resulting decimal value, "0.00")

Where 'resulting decimal value' refers to the result of your formula. Change the number of trailing zeroes to fit the output you require.